# Converting stateless to a class component react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component here that fills up a data for movies:

```
const MovieList = (props) => {

const movieItems = props.movies.map((movie) => {
  return <MovieListItem key={movie._id} movie={movie} />
});

  return(
    <div className="container">
    <h2 className="latest">MOVIE RESULTS</h2>
    <div className="row">
      { movieItems }
    </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Basically, I was planning to convert my next component where I am filling up my `movieItems` to a class component. This class has some helpers function along with a new function `onClickImgMoreBtn` whenever it was click it must console log something. But it doesnt work any more when I tried to convert it class component. Even my helper classes wont work either.

Here's my original stateless function:

```
import React from 'react';
const helper = require('../../helpers/helper_movies')

const MovieListItem = ({movie}) => {
  return (
<div>
                {helper.mappingComma(movie.genre)}
                {helper.getExcerpt(movie.overview)}
            <button className="btn btn-secondary float-right btn-sm" href={movie._id} onClick={this.onClickImgMoreBtn}>MORE</button>
</div>
);



};

export default MovieListItem;
```

And here's how i change it along with the new function:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const helper = require('../../helpers/helper_movies');

class MovieListItem extends Component{
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
  }

  onClickImgMoreBtn(){
    console.log('hi there!');
   }

  render(){
  return (
<div>
              {helper.mappingComma(this.props.genre)}
              {helper.getExcerpt(this.props.overview)}

            <button className="btn btn-secondary float-right btn-sm" href={this.props._id} onClick={this.onClickImgMoreBtn}>MORE</button>
</div>
);

}

}

export default MovieListItem;
```

Any idea what am i missing? did i properly converted it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your stateless component you destructure movie from the props and use `movie.genre,` `movie._id` and `movie.overview` and hence in the component you need to use
`this.props.movie.genre`, `this.props.movie._id` and `this.props.movie.overview`

```
render(){
  return (
         <div>
              {helper.mappingComma(this.props.movie.genre)}
              {helper.getExcerpt(this.props.movie.overview)}

            <button className="btn btn-secondary float-right btn-sm" href={this.props.movie._id} onClick={this.onClickImgMoreBtn}>MORE</button>
        </div>
   );
}
```

or better, `destructure movie form props` in render

```
render(){
  const { movie } = this.props;
  return (
         <div>
              {helper.mappingComma(movie.genre)}
              {helper.getExcerpt(movie.overview)}

            <button className="btn btn-secondary float-right btn-sm" href={movie._id} onClick={this.onClickImgMoreBtn}>MORE</button>
        </div>
   );
}
```

Also since you are not doing anything in the constructor, you need to have the constructor defined.

Comment: yeah but I was trying to add the simple onClickImgMoreBtn function to work with my data. That's why I decided to convert it.

Comment: @TonyBeatty, sure onClickImgMoreBtn  can be there without constructor

Comment: yeah i think you are right. thanks for the help it works now.